# update MD5 value not working in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have written a query to update a password using MD5. but the new password is not working, as well as the old password also. Below is the query.

```
UPDATE tbl_user
SET password = HashBytes('MD5', CAST(CHECKSUM('abc') AS varchar(32)))
WHERE login_id = 'user123'
```

Now when i give abc as a password it doesn't work, when i login to my application.

Comment: Lots of things could be going wrong here, unfortunately. What is the field type for `password`? How is the consuming application creating its hash for comparison? Is there a salt involved that you've forgotten to use?

Comment: dont use md5, it has been broken

Comment: Yuck...Its varchar(32) for password field. its the java code also for comparison of password using MD5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, never having done something exactly like that, but i think you need to enclose the value of the password `HashBytes('MD5', CAST(CHECKSUM('abc') AS varchar(32)))` in quotes, as in a normal query you would say

`UPDATE tbl_user SET password='complexpassword' WHERE login_id = 'user123'`

Oh and you probably ought to remove the brackets around login_id. With the password value not having quotes it does not no where the end of your string is and is probably trying to insert 
"HashBytes('MD5', CAST(CHECKSUM('abc') AS varchar(32)))WHERE (login_id = 'user123')" as your password and then finding it has no location info, that or it is recognizing your string and placing it as is in the table, not carrying out the hash.

The easiest thing could be to hash the password before passing it to the query statement. Tell me if that does not work in your situation and if the above fixes do not work.

Comment: well i am using sql server so it puts the brackets by itself. I will try this solution also.